# Solve initial value problem for $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=u$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$\begin{cases}u_{tt}-u_{xx}=u;\ ( 0 < x < 2,\ y > 0)\\
u(0,t)=2t,\ u(2,t)=0;\\
u(x,o)=0,\ u_t(x,o)=0.\end{cases}$

Firstly, I tried to separate $u$ as follow:

$u=v+w,\ w=A(t)x+B(t)$

$\begin{cases}u(0,t)=2t,\\u(2,t)=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}A=-t,\\B=2t\end{cases}$

then got

$w=-tx+2t$

and

$u=v-tx+2t$

then can think about this part:

$\begin{cases}v_{tt}-v_{xx}=v-tx+2t;\\ v(0,t)=v(2,t)=0; \\ v(x,o)=0, v_{t}(x,0)=x-2.\end{cases}$

I used separation of variables and got:

$v=X(x)T(t)$

$XT''-X''T=XT$

$\frac{T''-T}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda^2$

$\begin{cases}X''+\lambda^2x=0;\\X(0)=X(2)=0.\end{cases}\Rightarrow$

$1) X=0, v=0;\\2) \lambda_k=\frac{\pi k}{2}, k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$

Took the second result and got

$X_k=\sin{\lambda_kx}=\sin{\frac{\pi k}{2}x}, k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$

Then $v$ should be like:

$v=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}T_kX_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}T_k\sin{\frac{\pi k}{2}x}$

I am a little confused about how to continue to solve this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct so my answer will continue from there. We already established the Ansatz $v=\sum_{k=1}^\infty T_k(t)\sin\tfrac{\pi k x}{2}$. We plug it into the differential equation to get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty T_k''(t)\sin\tfrac{\pi k x}{2}+(\tfrac{\pi k}{2})^2T_k(t)\sin\tfrac{\pi k x}{2}-T_k(t)\sin\tfrac{\pi k x}{2}=2t-xt
$$
Multiplying by $\sin\tfrac{\pi j x}{2}$ and integrating from $0$ to $2$ yields:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Big(T_k''(t)+(\tfrac{\pi k}{2})^2T_k(t)-T_k(t)\Big)\underbrace{\int_0^2\sin\tfrac{\pi k x}{2}\sin\tfrac{\pi j x}{2}dx}_{=\delta_{kj}}=\underbrace{\int_0^2 (2t-xt)\sin\tfrac{\pi j x}{2}dx}_{=\frac{4t}{\pi j}}\\
\Rightarrow T_j''(t)+(\tfrac{\pi j}{2})^2T_j(t)-T_j(t)=\frac{4t}{\pi j}
$$
Similarly you achieve the intial conditions $T_j(0))=T_j'(0)=0$. This set of ODEs can be solved explicitely
$$
T_j(t)=\frac{\lambda_jt-2\sin\tfrac{\lambda_jt}{2}}{\lambda_j^3\pi j}
$$
with $\lambda_j=\sqrt{\pi^2m^2-4}$. Thus the full solution is given by
$$
u(x,t)=2t-xt+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda_jt-2\sin\tfrac{\lambda_jt}{2}}{\lambda_j^3\pi j}\sin\tfrac{\pi j x}{2}.
$$